# How to load data from cache using AFNetworking in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell, afnetworking-2

I'm using the AFNetworking library to call web services. My app has image views inside collection view cells and table view cells. Each time my app loads,  it takes a lot of time to load the images. So I would like a way to load images from the cache. I have attached a part of my code.

```
- (void)loadcategoryData
{
    post = nil;
    NSString *mainurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some url"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
    [manager GET:mainurl parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        posts = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        post = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(NSDictionary *all in posts)
        {
            Categories *category = [Categories new];
            category.title = [all objectForKey:@"catname"];
            category.firsturl = [all objectForKey:@"url"];

            [self.maincollectionView reloadData];
            //call for images

            imagespost = nil;
            NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", category.firsturl];
            AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *managerone = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
            [managerone GET:imageUrl parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                imagesposts = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
                NSArray *resultone = [imagesposts objectForKey:@"posts"];
                imagespost = [NSMutableArray array];
                if ([resultone count]) {
                    NSDictionary *firstpost = resultone[0];
//                    Categories *newmogocat = [Categories new];

                    NSDictionary *thumbnail_images = [firstpost objectForKeyedSubscript:@"thumbnail_images"];
                    NSDictionary *thumbnail = [thumbnail_images objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
                    category.imageOneUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[thumbnail objectForKey:@"url"]];
//                    NSLog(@"%@", newmogocat.imageOneUrl);
//                    [imagespost addObject:newmogocat];

                    [post addObject:category];

                    [self.maincollectionView reloadData];
                }

            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                UIAlertView *erroralert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Something Wrong!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error.localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [erroralert show];

            }];                                
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError * responseObject) {

    }];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableUserInfo = [[cachedResponse userInfo] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableData *mutableData = [[cachedResponse data] mutableCopy];
    NSURLCacheStoragePolicy storagePolicy = NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly;

    return [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:[cachedResponse response] data:mutableData userInfo:mutableUserInfo storagePolicy:storagePolicy];
}
```

---

**And this is the return cell**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CategoryCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellidentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
//    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;

    [cell addSubview:cell.maintitleLabel];

    Categories *cat = [post objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.maincollectionView reloadInputViews];
    cell.maintitleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", cat.title];
    [cell.maintitleLabel sizeToFit];               

    NSString *mainstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cat.imageOneUrl];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:mainstring];
//
    [cell.mainImageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil];
//

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a separate class. Each object of this class knows how to download a single image asynchronously, and cache it as well as notify the image view it's associated with that the image is ready to display...

Lucky for you AFNetworking already has this written for you. Check out its extension to UIImageView. With this extension, you just pass the image's URL to your UIImageView (with `setImageWithURL`) and it does all the hard work for you.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h

For those not using AFNetworking, Apple has sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html